# Timepicker not updating

Tags: android

Calling *setCurrentMinute()* doesn't change the displayed time.

```
public void updateTimer(int minute) {
    Log.d(TAG, "minute: " + minute);  // prints out as expected
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);        
    timePicker.invalidate();
}
```

Interestingly enough, when initializing, it does work, as when the Activity (and Fragment) open, it shows 4 Minutes. Invalidate does not help either.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_set_time, container, false);

    timePicker = (EuropeanTimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(0);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(4);
}
```

Comment: May I suggest a better version of the time picker here https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker

Comment: Nice but another dependency which requires yet another dependency

Comment: Nah, just download the source and remove any crap from nineolddroids and use the stock android object animators if you are targeting levels >= 11.